# CodeIgniter: pagination shows "per_page" twice?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using CI's pagination library. Here's my config:

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config                   = array();
$config['base_url']       = 'http://localhost/index.php/search/';
$config['total_rows']     = 200;
$config['per_page']       = 10;
$config['num_links']      = 4;

$config['full_tag_open']  = '<ol>';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</ol>';

$config['first_link']      = 'First';
$config['first_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['last_link']      = 'Last';
$config['last_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['next_link']      = 'Next';
$config['next_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['prev_link']      = 'Previous';
$config['prev_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['cur_tag_open']  = '<li class="active">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$config['num_tag_open']  = '<li>';
$config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';

$this->pagination->initialize($config);
echo htmlentities($this->pagination->create_links());
echo ($this->pagination->create_links());
```

The resulting links has `per_page` twice, such as yo see here:

`http://localhost/index.php/search/&per_page=&per_page=10`. **Any ideas why?**

Comment: Which? The one with localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are echoing it two times in the two last lines of the code

Replace:

```
echo htmlentities($this->pagination->create_links());
echo ($this->pagination->create_links());
```

To:

```
echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

And you should pass your variables to the views instead of echoing it from the controller.

Comment: I did the `htmlentities` as a way to help me debug this; didn't realize it was causing my problems. Yes, I plan to assign the results of `$this->pagination->create_links();` to a Smarty variable and let the views handle this. Thanks!